# What technique does blender use ofr Smart UV unwrap?

Tags: texturing, uv, geometry

I am writing an academic document and need to cite blender. The issue is, I need to be able to name the technique it uses. I assume it probably uses somthing like ABF++ or LSCM, but I don't know for sure.

I tried looking into the docs but no luck, does anyone have a hint on where to find which parametrization algorithm is the basis for Blender's implementation?